# Making buttons disappear depending on the size of a list

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to make a button disappear off the screen when the size of a list that is being filled by the user reaches a size of lets say 3 items.

The button is for "adding a new person" but once the list is full i don't want that to be an option to add another person to the list.

I have tried the following code but the program doesn't run

```
Private Sub Form1_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseMove

    If inputNames.Count >= 3 Then   'inputnames is the name of the list
        Button1.Visible = False     'button 1 is the add a new person button
    End If
End Sub
```

could someone please help me? the program doesn't even open.
I just want the button to go away when the number of elements in a list is greater than a specific number lets just say 3 for now

I can also include the rest of the code for my program

Comment: Doesn't compile? Crashes directly after startup? Freezes? What does doesn't run mean? Perhaps crashes directly after moving mouse pointer over the form? Make sure `inputNames` is not `Nothing` when first entering with the mouse pointer.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    If ListBox1.Items.Count >= 2 Then
        'your add code
        Button2.Visible = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    If ListBox1.Items.Count >= 2 Then
        Button2.Visible = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: if you not using listbox then write proper what control you using

Comment: The "list" is probably a [**`List(Of T)`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx). Either way he calls it by its name in the question.

Comment: Inputheight.items.count doesn't seem to work either. The items thing doesn't pop up when typing only item

Comment: @JordanH : That's because `Items` is only a sub-property of the `ListBox`. For lists it's just `.Count`.