# Making buttons disappear and appear in visual basic depending on the size of a list

Tags: vb.net

Basically, my windows form application is a program where you enter a person's name into a text box and their height in cm into another text box. When a button called btnAddNewPerson is clicked the inputs in the text boxes go to 2 different lists called **lstNames** and **lstHeight**. Once  a certain amount of people have been added and the calculate button is clicked (btnCalc) then a message box appears with the tallest smallest and average height.

The problem i am having is that i want the Add New Person button to disappear (become invisible) once a certain amount of entries has been made. And i want the calculate button to only appear once a certain amount of entries have been made (don't want premature calculations).

I have tried the following code but it doesn't work.
The program crashes the second i move the mouse and the error i get is

***"An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Height Finder.exe
Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."***

```
Private Sub frmHeightFinder_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseMove
    If lstNames.Count >= 4 Then
        btnAddNewPerson.Visible = False
    Else btnAddNewPerson.Visible = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Question is, how are you calling this method? How does the compiler know how to execute this method? and when to?

Comment: [**Please don't ask the same question twice**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42468424/making-buttons-disappear-depending-on-the-size-of-a-list) (especially not with different accounts!)

Comment: i understand why but i did it because i was under time constraints and i couldn't write another question due to a 1 day ban for it being a negative rating question. Since i didn't clearly write what i wanted i decided to rewrite the question. I wont do it in the future though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's crashing before you click the button (i.e. when you move the mouse), there's something wrong with the mouse event call. A better way to do this is to check in your AddPerson method if your condition (lstnames.Count > 4) is met, and then make it invisible. Further, it might be a good idea to just disable the button, instead of making it invisible.
An example:

```
Private Sub btnAddNewPerson_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    ' Add person to the list code here

    If lstNames.Count >= 4 Then
        btnAddNewPerson.Enabled = False
        btnCalc.Enabled = True ' I assume this is what you want here
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Edit: Seems to be working but still need to make a few changes. Ill let you know if it plays up again

Comment: Alright. Please remember to accept the answer. Good luck.